# How to mock ReaciveMongoTemplate aggregate method when I want to return different results for 2 queries

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, junit, aggregation-framework

`I'm writing Junit test cases for my DAO layer. My Update method fetches details of a document and if it is present then updates this document. **When I'm trying to mock the ReactiveMongoTemplate aggregate method it returns null**

**Here's snip of my DAO method :**

```
 @Autowired
private ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public void method() {

//some code

MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(new Criteria(FolderConfigurationServiceConstants.DOCUMENT_TYPE)
                .is(DocumentTypes.ROOT));
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match);
        
Flux<MongoDocumentDetails> document = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collection, MongoDocumentDetails.class);

//some code
}
```

and another aggregation operation is :

```
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(new Criteria(FolderConfigurationServiceConstants.DOCUMENT_TYPE)
                .is(DocumentTypes.DIRECTORY)
                .andOperator(Criteria.where("name").is(name),                       Criteria.where(FolderConfigurationServiceConstants.PARENT_PATH).is(fetchGrandParent(parentPathArray, lengthOfArray).toString())));
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match);
        
Flux<MongoDocumentDetails> parentDocument = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collection, MongoDocumentDetails.class);
```

Now, I want to mock the aggregate method with a particular response when mongotemplate calls the aggregate method. How can I do this? I want to have 2 different results.

**My Test method looks like :**

```
@Test
void method()
{
//some code
  Mockito.doReturn(Flux.just(getDocument()))
        .when(mongoTemplate).aggregate(aggregationForRoot, COLLECTION, MongoDocumentDetails.class);
//ideally it should return a document on execution but returns null
}
```